# RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND while creating Subscription Api response in PayPal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am using PayPal payment integration in my code.

I have created a product and plan in PayPal account and I want to use PayPal monthly/yearly subscription buttons.

I copied code from PayPal developer site and put in my code but it is not working.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dm6M.png)

Below is my code

```
    <script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'subscribe'
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          /* Creates the subscription */
          plan_id: 'P-XXXX7066V2124102XXXXXX'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container-P-7L763248U6625362UMLLHPYQ'); // Renders the PayPal button
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation for a RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND error is if your plan_id does not correspond to (was not created under/using) the client id the SDK is loaded with.

In particular, from the error it's evident you're using a client id from the sandbox environment. This means that you need to be able to find that plan id by [logging into the sandbox environment](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans) using the [sandbox business account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts) that corresponds to [the sandbox mode app with the client_id you are using](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications).

If the plan_id cannot be found within that client_id's sandbox account, and especially if you are mixing a plan_id from the live environment with a sandbox client_id (the two environments are completely separate), RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND is the expected error.

---

If that isn't enough to resolve your issue, your question needs to be specific about which exact plan_id and client id you are using, to test their correspondence.